# Hide a VueJS component with v-if

Tags: vue.js

I have a website and on login I put on localStorage the username from the login. So this is on Login.Vue

```
login() {
  axios.post('/login', this.user)
  .then((response) => {
    alertify.set('notifier','delay', 3);
    alertify.success("Success! You are now logged in.");

    axios.get("/user", this.user)
    .then((response) => {
      this.$router.push('/home');
      AuthPlugin.setUser(this.user.username);
    })
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    alertify.set('notifier','delay', 0);
    alertify.error('Invalid User');
  });
}
```

I do that using a AuthPlugin made by me that does this:

```
setUser(user) {
    localStorage.setItem('authUser', user);
}
```

On Header.vue, the component that is on each page, I have the username showing up on each page saying that he is online.

```
<template>
    <div id="header-bar" v-if="!username">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded p-0 fixed-top">
        <a href="#">Your are online {{username}}</a>
        <a href="#"  @click="logout">Log out</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  import AuthPlugin from '../../plugin/Auth.js';
  import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                users: {},
                username: localStorage.authUser
            }
        },
        methods: {
          logout() {
            AuthPlugin.destroyToken();
                AuthPlugin.destroyUser();
                this.$router.push('/');
          },
          getUsers() {
                axios.get("/user")
                  .then((response) => {
                        this.users = response;
                  })
          }
       }
    }
</script>
```

Here on logout I destroy the token and user in AuthPlugin

```
destroyToken() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('authTokenExpiration');
},
destroyUser() {
    localStorage.removeItem('authUser');
}
```

I put the header comp on App.vue to be on each page.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-header></app-header>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

So when I do logout I remove authUser from localStorage. I want when I click on logout and get redirected to "/", which is login component, that header to be hidden.

These are the routes

```
export const routes = [
  {path: '/', component: Login},
  {path: '/home', component: Home, meta: {requiresAuth: true}},
  {path: '/events', component: Events, meta: {requiresAuth: true}},
  {path: '/events/new-event', component: NewEvent, meta: {requiresAuth: true}},
  {path: '/events/edit-event/:id', component: EditEvent, meta: {requiresAuth: true}}
]
```

Right now if I click on logout, when I get redirected to login the header is gone, but when I enter the username and pass to login and enter to the website the header is still hidden.

Why the header is hidden? If I type in browser console localStore.authUser and hit enter I see the username that I used to log in.

Please someone tell, what I did wrong in that v-if? Or please tell if I can hide that header on logout with a diff method.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do so seems to be this put a meta tag in router.js -

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      meta: { hideNavigation: true }
    }
  ]
})
```

and use this in the Vue template -

```
<navigation v-if="!$route.meta.hideNavigation" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Header` component is watching its *own* `username` property for changes.
When you instantiate the component, the value is copied from `localStorage` once.

My suggestion is to make the username (and optionally the user) a property of your root Vue object and update it in your `setUser` function.
You can then either pass the username as a prop to the `Header` component, or use `vm.$watch` to update the component's `username` when the Vue instance username changes.

Comment: My friend what u say was my first try. I tried that for 2 days in diff ways: watchers, props but was't working at all. Or maybe I didn't set them how should be. How is right now was the only solution that on logout the header to be hidden. On other solutions the header doesn't disappear when I click on logoff.

Answer (score 1):

Possible work around:

```
<div id="header-bar" v-if="!username && !$route.path === '/'">
```

Comment: I tried my friend your code but still the header is not showing after login. If I put like this, that doesn't make sense to use it, ` v-if="username"`, the header is present after login and logout. So is still not good.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing put v-if check in App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-header v-if="!username"></app-header>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

And data:

```
data() {
       return {
         username: localStorage.authUser
       }
```

},

This will bind the header directly.

Comment: Thant works but on route like this `/events/new-event` doesn't work. Works only on main routes `/home` and `/events`. It's very strange.